# How to convert predicate Func<TModel, bool> into Func<TEntity, bool> when develop Repository class. TModel - BL model, TEntity - Db entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I develop simple app with Business layer and Data access layer (using EF). On my **BL** I define interfase **IRepository**.

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    public Task<T> GetAsync(object id);

    public Task<T> GetFirstByAsync(Func<T, bool> predicate);

    public Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync();

    public Task<int> CountAsync();

    public Task<T> AddAsync(T @object);

    public Task AddRangeAsync(IEnumerable<T> objects);

    public Task DeleteAllAsync();
}
```

Also on **BL** I have **Parameter** model

```
public class Parameter : IEquatable<Parameter>
{
    private readonly double _tolerance;

    public int Number { get; }

    public string Name { get; }

    public double LowerLimit { get; }

    public double UpperLimit { get; }

    public string Unit { get; }

    public Parameter(int number, string name, double lowerLimit, double upperLimit, string unit)
    {
        if (number < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Parameter number cannot be less than 0");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
        }

        if (lowerLimit >= upperLimit)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Parameter {nameof(lowerLimit)} cannot be >= {nameof(upperLimit)}");
        }

        Number = number;
        Name = name;
        LowerLimit = lowerLimit;
        UpperLimit = upperLimit;
        Unit = unit;

        _tolerance = (upperLimit - lowerLimit) / 1e10;
    }

    public bool Equals(Parameter other)
    {
        if (other is null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return Number == other.Number && Name == other.Name && Unit == other.Unit;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return HashCode.Combine(Number, Name, Unit);
    }

    public bool StrongEquals(Parameter other)
    {
        return Equals(other) &&
               Math.Abs(LowerLimit - other.LowerLimit) < _tolerance &&
               Math.Abs(UpperLimit - other.UpperLimit) < _tolerance;
    }
}
```

On **DAL** I have **Parameter** entity

```
public class Parameter : BaseEntity
{
    public int Number { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public double LowerLimit { get; set; }

    public double UpperLimit { get; set; }

    public string Unit { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Measurement> Measurements { get; set; } //navigation
}

public class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

So then I start to develop **ParameterReporitory** class on **DAL** which implements IRepository. In such case I decided to close interface type with a parameter 'Parameter' from BL because from BL perspective it's not neccessary to work with the entity classes themselves. My BL and DAL models are basically small so it's not neccessary for me to use some mapping library such Automapper. I just wrote extensions methods **ToBusinessModel()/ ToDbEntity()** to convert BL model to DAL entity and backward. I can implement all interface methods in ParameterRepository besides **GetFirstBy(Func<ParameterModel, bool> predicate)** because I doubted whether it was right to try to do such a transformation **Func<ParameterModel, bool>** to **Func<ParameterEntity, bool>** like I did it in code. When I try to execute this method I get an exception

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(p => Invoke(__predicate_0, p.ToBusinessModel())
> )' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by
> inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or
> 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for
> more information.

**What can I do to prevent this exception and implement this method in repository class corectly?** Perhaps, I don't want to execute this expression on client side because it leads to get all entities from DB in memory and then filter them. So, what can I do other than that? Please pay attention to these definitions in the code

```
using ParameterEntity = DatabaseAccess.Models.Parameter;
using ParameterModel = BusinessLayer.Models.Parameter;
```

```
using DatabaseAccess.Extensions;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ParameterEntity = DatabaseAccess.Models.Parameter;
using ParameterModel = BusinessLayer.Models.Parameter;
using System.Linq;
using BusinessLayer.Interfaces;

namespace DatabaseAccess
{
    public class ParameterRepository : IRepository<ParameterModel>
    {
        private readonly MeasurementContext _context;
        private readonly DbSet<ParameterEntity> _dbSet;

        public ParameterRepository(MeasurementContext context)
        {
            _context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
            _dbSet = _context.Parameters;
        }

        public async Task<ParameterModel> GetAsync(object id) => (await _dbSet.FindAsync(id)).ToBusinessModel();
        
        public async Task<ParameterModel> GetFirstByAsync(Func<ParameterModel, bool> predicate)
        {
            Expression<Func<ParameterEntity, bool>> entityPredicate = x => predicate(x.ToBusinessModel());
            return (await _dbSet.Where(entityPredicate).FirstOrDefaultAsync()).ToBusinessModel();
        }

        public async Task<ParameterModel> AddAsync(ParameterModel parameterModel)
        {
            if (!await IsExistAsync(parameterModel))
            {
                _dbSet.Add(parameterModel.ToDbEntity());
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

            return parameterModel;
        }

        public async Task DeleteAllAsync()
        {
            _dbSet.RemoveRange(_dbSet);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        public async Task AddRangeAsync(IEnumerable<ParameterModel> parameterModels)
        {
            var uniqueParameters = parameterModels.Distinct();
            foreach (var parameter in uniqueParameters)
            {
                if (!await IsExistAsync(parameter))
                {
                    _dbSet.Add(parameter.ToDbEntity());
                }
            }

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<ParameterModel>> GetAllAsync() => (await _dbSet.ToListAsync()).ToBusinessModels();

        public async Task<int> CountAsync() => await _dbSet.CountAsync();

        public async Task<ParameterModel> FindByNumberAsync(int number) => (await _dbSet.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Number == number)).ToBusinessModel();

        public async Task<bool> IsExistAsync(ParameterModel parameterModel) => (await FindByNumberAsync(parameterModel.Number)) != null;
    }
}
```

My extension methods:

```
public static class MappingExtensions
{
    public static ParameterModel ToBusinessModel(this ParameterEntity parameter)
    {
        if (parameter is null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return new ParameterModel(
            parameter.Number,
            parameter.Name,
            parameter.LowerLimit,
            parameter.UpperLimit,
            parameter.Unit);
    }

    public static ParameterEntity ToDbEntity(this ParameterModel parameter)
    {
        if (parameter is null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return new ParameterEntity
        {
            Number = parameter.Number,
            Name = parameter.Name,
            LowerLimit = parameter.LowerLimit,
            UpperLimit = parameter.UpperLimit,
            Unit = parameter.Unit
        };
    }
}
```

I also wanted to know if this is a normal approach to create a repository class for an entity from BL (ParameterModel). Maybe it would be more correct to make a repository that works with ParameterEntity and then make something like a decorator as a repository that will already work with the ParameterModel (from BL). This decorator repository will call methods of decoratee repository. Or perhaps you can advise me on the best approach.

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.ExpressionMapping

Answer (score 1):

First, don't misleading `Func<T, bool>` and `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`.

**Func<T, bool>**

It's a delegate to invoke a method.

**Expression<Func<T, bool>>**

A expression can be parsed. For example to be translated to SQL like EF Core do.

---

> What can I do to prevent this exception and implement this method in repository class corectly?

EF Core translate expression to SQL to query the DB. For example, the expression :

```cs
Expression<Func<ParameterEntity, bool>> predicateExp = x => x.Name.Contains("foo");
```

is translated to `[name] like '%foo%'`. But how do you want it translate this?

```cs
ParameterModel m = x.ToBusinessModel();
bool predicateResult = predicate(m);
return predicateResult;
```

EF Core don't know and throw the error you see. To avoid the error, you can use [client evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval) :

```cs
public async Task<ParameterModel> GetFirstByAsync(Func<ParameterModel, bool> predicate)
{
    Expression<Func<ParameterEntity, bool>> entityPredicate = x => predicate(x.ToBusinessModel());
    return (await _dbSet.ToList().Where(entityPredicate).FirstOrDefaultAsync()).ToBusinessModel();
}
```

With `ToList()`, EF Core will load the full table in memory and it's the C# program that will apply the predicate. If the table has a lot of row, this can be a big memory pressure... **don't do this**.

---

> Perhaps, I don't want to execute this expression on client side because it leads to get all entities from DB in memory and then filter them. So, what can I do other than that?

EF Core can't translate `Expression<Func<ParameterModel, bool>>` to `Expression<Func<ParameterEntity, bool>>`. But you can manually parse `Expression<Func<ParameterModel, bool>>` to generate `Expression<Func<ParameterEntity, bool>>`.

It's can be funny and challenging, but need a lot of work and sound error prone... I don't recommend.

---

> Or perhaps you can advise me on the best approach.

My favorite advise about repository pattern with EF Core is **don't use the repository pattern**. Use directly the DbContext, DbContext is the DAL.

The rare case when the repository pattern is useful, it's to encapsulate all access to the DB. It's help to have a good view on db access and optimize the DB.

In the OP code, the repository allow to filter on all columns... you need to inspect all code to find that index is necessary in the DB.

But if the repository allow only to filter on ID and name, then you only need to add the index on this corresponding columns.

Comment: How can I use DbContext directly?  BL shouldn’t know anything about DbContext. For example, in my simple case I can want to create storage in memory without using database and replace Db implementation with in memory implementation. In such case I need to create some abstraction which allow me to get access to storage and work with it

Comment: Software development is all about compromises. Without context, I can just share my experience and do generic recommendation.

Comment: See this other question : [To Repository Or Not To Repository](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/237374/to-repository-or-not-to-repository)

Comment: Thanks for your advices. I don’t ready to stop using Repository pattern because I often see how this pattern works in the real app code and I want to have possibility to change implementation and keep BL and DAL loosely coupled. For now I think maybe I shouldn’t use such common method with Func. Maybe it’s enough for me to have  search only by several properties like Id, Number and Name. Maybe it’s not the best way using generic repository especially with this method. It would be nice to get someone else's point of view